# Android drawable images int

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I am using large number of images in drawable folder
And i want to get it all in

```
int[] images = new int[] {
R.drawable.pic4
R.drawable.pic3
R.drawable.pic2
};
```

Is there any way to get all without writing the names of images one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your Drawables like pic1,pic2,pic3.....picN.

Then you can get those Drawables by,

```
    int [] drawables=new int[N];
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        drawables[i] = getResources()
                .getIdentifier("pic"+i, "drawable", getPackageName()));
    }
```

I hope it will help you. All the best.

Comment: Thanks i will try and replay to u

Comment: But i want to get all images as int[] ... How to do it with using your answer code

Comment: Zombie i dont understand u...  where i use your coee and what it work?

Comment: I set N = 4 and use this code but the viewpager show me one image but it not named pic.  its name is image_9.jpg

Comment: Rename it to pic9. You should keep your images in order like pic1,pic2,pic3. You can change "pic" to any name you want. but all your drawables(Related to this) should have same name with the suffix number. Some Examples {pic1.png,pic2.png,pic3.png} {image_1.png,image_2.png,imge_3.png} {photo1.png,phot2.png}

Comment: Thanks its work.... But the first image in the viewpager in none when i use your code the images begin show after first swip.. Why....?? And how to set images start show without first swip...and thank u for helping me..

Comment: Post your related code(view pager) where you are using above code. Then only I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

i think you've done a good job naming the image pic2, pic3.....

this might help a lot. you can write a while loop and keep on going until you end up with a name that doesn't have any resource file

this class would get the drawable for you

```
    public class ImageHelper
{
    public static int getImageId(Context context, String name, String param)
    {
        try
        {
            name = param == null ? name : (name  + param.toLowerCase());
            int res = getResId(context, name, R.drawable.class);
            if (res == 0)
            {
                Log.d("ImageHelper", "missing drawable: " + name);
            }
            return res;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static int getResId(Context context, String resName, Class<?> c)
    {
        try
        {
            return context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, c.getSimpleName(), context.getPackageName());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

use it like this

```
String imageName = "pic";
int index = 0; // or any index you want to start with

ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    int resourceId = ImageHelper.getImageId(context, imageName, "" + index);
    index++;
    if (resourceId > 0){
        images.add(resourceId);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide an example of how this is used.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to store the listing of your drawables in an XML array. This is not an exact solution to your problem but at least it can result in a cleaner Java code.

#### res/values/arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="my_drawables">
        <item>@drawable/image1</item>
        <item>@drawable/image2</item>
        <item>@drawable/image3</item>
        <!-- Add other drawables -->
    </array>
</resources>
```

#### In your code

```
final TypedArray drawableArray = getResources()
    .obtainTypedArray(R.array.my_drawables);

// Example of using the array.
// Parameters are as follow: getResourceId(int index, int defValue)
// and it provides the int value of the desired drawable.
myImageView.setImageResource(drawableArray.getResourceId(1, -1));
```

This implementation still requires to write once the list of drawables but you eliminate possible errors cause by hardcoded strings in for cycles and it's easy to use across your code.

Comment: Steel must write the images names in your idea

Comment: @user6951371 yes but I believe it is the cleanest and most fail safe idea.

Comment: Have u another idea?